# Change connection string without rebuild

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web.config-transform

Generally projects are created using the below method:

Create a solution with 1 DAL class (this has a dbml file). Create a 2nd class project called BLL which is the business layer that creates the CRUD operations. Finally have a Asp .Net project.

First thing i do is in the DAL (Data Access Layer) i create a connection to the database and drag the required tables. 
I create code to get,edit data etc, in the BLL project. 
I then have to add a connection string in the Asp .Net project so it can connect to the database.

The issue i always seem to face is when i deploy the project to a test server i can change the Asp .Net projects web.config connection string easily, but at first run the application breaks (cant connect to the sql database) as in the DAL is still looking at the original connection string. So what i have to do is set the new connection string in the DAL project compile and copy that across which then allows everything to work.

I face the same issue when going from the test server to the live server. I've read about using config files but this is as far as i understand they can be used..... But surely there must be an easier way to,change the connection string in one place without having to recompile my DAL dll?

Are there tricks im missing or addons i could use to take advantage of?

Comment: You figured it out on your own. Yes use a config file.

Comment: Are you not using `web.config` in your project solution?

Comment: I'm using a web.config file but as i stated the ASP .Net web project connects to the new connection string BUT I have to recompile the DAL which seems to be using the previous connection. Please note there are 3 different projects here

Comment: Why it needs to be recompiled? You need to read connection string from web.config rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel please note the connection is based on two projects

Comment: My mistake, then where does connection string comes from?

Comment: @Computer I understand that you have three different projects but are they not housed under a single project solution? If your `Web` project can read the new connection string then why not the `DAL` project read the new connection string from the `web.config` which is part of web project but can be accessible from your `Web/DAL/BLL` projects?

Comment: Just use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"].ConnectionString;` from your DLL project, so all projects will be referencing the same updated connection settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use 2 connection string(one in web.config of your UI and the other one on your Data Access) and you dont want to depend of a specific database(in this case SQL Server), you can use just a single connection string on your web.config UI.

When you done that, on your DA, just use the DLL **Microsoft.Practices.Enterprise.Data** so you will not depend of SQL for connections.

Next time, when you want to migrate your application, for example, from SQL to Oracle, since you are not using anymore SQLConnection, you just change your connection string and its done!. Your migration to Oracle its done in 1 minute.

Comment: Ok this sounds like what I'm after. I will research on Microsoft.Practices.Enterprise.Data. Any examples you could point me to would be great. If this works i will mark your response as the answer - thanks

Comment: There is 2 different ways to do this: use the dll or create your own class using the reference System.Data.common.dbconnection. Remember once you implement this, change all your sqlconnections or sql references for your call to the Database(your class or the dll), so you from now on dont depend of sql to connect to your database.